# Let a, b, c, d be real numbers such that a < b and c < d. Prove that |[a,b] x [c,d]| = c

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $a, b, c, d$ be real numbers such that $a < b$ and $c < d$. Prove that $|[a,b]$ x $[c,d]| = c$. This $c$ on the end is the 'cardinality of the continuum' which means that the set has the same cardinality as the set of real numbers.

I am a bit confused as to where to start with this. Does this mean that the elements of the set are  {c,a}, {c,b}, {a,d}, {b,d} where $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers and $a < b$ and $c < d$?

There is a theorem that if $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers and $a < b$ and $c < d$ then $(a,b]$ and $(c,d]$ have the same cardinality. Would this be of any use?

Comment: You mean `\frak c`.

Comment: The set is a closed rectangle.  [a,b] is the closed interval so [a,b]x[c,d] is the interval "crossed" with another.  In other words, a rectangle.  The set is {(x,y)$\in \mathbb R^2$| a$\le $x $\le$ b and  c$\le $x $\le$ d}.